# Links to the reputation leagues are broken on MathOverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, users, hyperlinks

At the bottom of [the users page](https://mathoverflow.net/users) you can find links to weekly / monthly / quarterly reputation leagues. Currently there is the following link: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/mathoverflow - it returns "page not found".

The correct link should have `mathoverflow.net` instead of `mathoverflow`, see here: [Why the links with “leagues/{site-name}” do not work for all sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321706) The link https://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/mathoverflow.net indeed works. Another working link is https://stackexchange.com/leagues/504/week/mathoverflow. (The number used in the latter format, was changed at some point - it [used to be 251](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306575/what-was-the-reason-to-change-ids-in-the-links-to-reputation-leagues).)

Could this be corrected, please?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the links, @Adam Lear!

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Sure thing, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of last week, we also check for `.net` as a possible way to complete a valid domain, so `https://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/mathoverflow` will work going forward.